# How to force the use of an ip of my server

Tags: networking, interface, eth0

How to force the use of an ip of my server
**eth0:1**, if my server interoge example google.com

when i use my php scripts, the ip that google must see is **eth0:1**

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 173.249.3.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 173.249.3.1
    dns-search invalid
    dns-nameservers 213.136.95.10 213.136.95.11
    up ip route replace 173.249.3.0/24 via 173.249.3.1 dev eth0

# new ip
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 164.68.125.112
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 164.68.125.1
```

Comment: Do you have a dns entry associated with either IP address? And what do you mean by `the ip that google must see` ? Do you mean the search tool, or Chrome, or the company?

Comment: sorry for my bad english, no google is an example, I work with aliexpress and with API but it allows only 1 connection by ip

Comment: Sorry, it's just a little unclear what the problem is, and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I voted for the duplicate, as you can see inside it some command to use, like ip route add  8.8.8.8/16 via 164.68.125.112 , but you will have to find the public subnet google use